# Difficulty web scraping with beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use Beautiful Soup to extract the title of a job. The title in the span tag is the same as the text. Eg: text is 'Barista' but so is the title. So far I've been using .findall but idk how it can work for this.

Sample html:

```
<h2 class="jobTitle jobTitle-color-purple jobTitle-newJob">
 <div class="new topLeft holisticNewBlue desktop">
   <span class="label">new</span>
 </div>
 <span title="Barista">Barista</span>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the recursive attribute from beautifulSoup, to get just the direct child of h2.

I tested the following code sample and it works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_str = '''<h2 class="jobTitle jobTitle-color-purple jobTitle-newJob">
                <div class="new topLeft holisticNewBlue desktop">
                  <span class="label">new</span>
                </div>
                <span title="Barista">Barista</span>
              </h2>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str, 'lxml')
title = soup.h2.find('span', recursive=False).text
print(title)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
# Imports.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# HTML code.
html_str = '''<h2 class="jobTitle jobTitle-color-purple jobTitle-newJob">
                <div class="new topLeft holisticNewBlue desktop">
                  <span class="label">new</span>
                </div>
                <span title="Barista">Barista</span>
              </h2>'''

# Parsing HTML.
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str, 'lxml')
# Searching for `span` tags with `title` attributes.
list_html_titles = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'title': True})
# Getting titles from HTML code blocks.
list_titles = [x.text for x in list_html_titles]
```